# Autorotate parent view to portrait when child view is dismissed ios6

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

login view controller embedded in navigation controller must be only portrait.
other view controller's pushed can rotate.
scenario:
if after signing in i rotate child view controller and then logout login view controller appears in landscape.

logincontroller(portrait)->rotated device->childcontroller(landscape)->back->logincontroller(landscape)

I want login controller to be portrait when I come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type these two methods in your login ViewController

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { return YES;
}

(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown); }
```

and

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotate { return YES;
}

(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); }
```

in your childcontroller

required to add category autorotation subclassed navigation controller which would call topcontroller shouldautorotate and supported interface orientation.

```
#import "UINavigationController+Autorotation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Autorotation)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
for (UIViewController * viewController in self.viewControllers) {
    if (![viewController isEqual:self.topViewController]) {
        [viewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
}

return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
for (UIViewController * viewController in self.viewControllers) {
    if (![viewController isEqual:self.topViewController]) {
        [viewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
}

return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

type these two methods in your login ViewController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;    
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | 
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;    
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | 
            UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

in your childcontroller

Comment: Also i required to add category autorotation subclassed navigation controller which would call topcontroller shouldautorotate and supported interface orientation.